# Bootstrap 3 div vertical-horizontal full screen center - CSS solution - worked for me

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

It was buggin me for a while, so maybe someone else finds it useful.

HTML:

```
    <div class="parent-center-center-1">
    <div class="parent-center-center-2">
      <div class="parent-center-center-3">
        <div class="child-center-center">
          Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes Content for New Div Tag Goes 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .parent-center-center-1 {
    background-color: #F00;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.parent-center-center-2 {
    background-color: #090;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

.parent-center-center-3 {
    background-color: #FF0;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.child-center-center {
    background-color:#F00;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is about it, just copy and paste. It also works if you put child in "container".